# Adding a ssh host key for a server name to `known_hosts` idempotently?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen, hostkey

`ssh-keygen -R $HOSTNAME` can remove the ssh host key(s) from one's `known_hosts`. Can I add a specific host key (for a hostname/ip) to a `known_hosts` in an idempotent way?

I want to script ssh'ing into a server. This might be run by someone who has not ssh'ed into that server before, and hence the server's host key would not be in the `known_hosts` file, so they would be asked to accept it. I would like to remove this step, to make everything streamlined. How can I do this?

`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no …` disabled that sercurity, which has downsides. `ssh-keyscan $HOSTNAME > ~/.ssh/known_hosts` will work, but the `known_hosts` file will constantly grow, and will update the file with the *current* host key. Is there a way to do this *idempotently*, for a fixed, defined servername & host key combo? i.e. “If you don't have $HOST_KEY for $HOSTNAME, add that to your `known_hosts`”?

This script will run on Ubuntu 18.04 with OpenSSH client v7.6

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ssh-keygen` to check if the `known_hosts` file contains entries for a specific host, like this:

```
lacek@Teloth:~$ ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F 192.168.153.254
# Host 192.168.153.254 found: line 18 
192.168.153.254 ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza.....
```

You can use this to check the presence of a host key, and add it if it is not found, something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTNAME=host.to.ssh.into
KNOWNHOSTS=~/.ssh/known_hosts

ssh-keygen -F $HOSTNAME -f $KNOWNHOSTS | grep -q found || ssh-keyscan $HOSTNAME >>$KNOWNHOSTS 2>/dev/null
```